# Changing colour of VLC Volume Slider?

Tags: vlc-media-player, colors

By going to `Preferences > All > Interface > Main Interface > QT`
I found that we can change the colour of the volume slider. Since I never use volume above 100%, I changed the max volume displayed to 100%.

But when I went about to change the colour of the volume slider, I couldn't understand how it works. The default setting were as follows:

> 153;210;153;20;210;20;255;199;15;245;39;29

So, I changed the values, as desired, to these:

> 300;285;270;255;240;225;210;195;180;165;150;135

But I got this:

[image]

I wanted these colours:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after some try!

These are the RGB values. So each three sets of values determines the colour.

Example:

> I used the following values:
>
> > 0;0;255;0;255;0;0;255;0;0;255;0

`0;0;255` stand for Blue.
`0;255;0` stand for green.

`0;0;255;0;255;0;0;255;0;0;255;0
[ Blue ][        Green         ]`

And I got the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you wanted to use the actual colours you specified in your question:

[image]

Use `255;0;255;64;0;255;0;191;255;0;255;64`

Or in reverse:

[image]

```
0;255;64;0;191;255;64;0;255;255;0;255
```